# Set Operation Exclusion Constraint for Multiple Tables All at Once

Tags: postgresql, constraint, exclusion-constraint

In multiple of my tables, I have a `deleted` column for tracking things which have been deleted, instead of directly deleting them from the database.

As such, I would like to create a constraint for disallowing the *undeletion* of things, preferably all at once. Is that even possible?

To exemplify things:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS users (
    id UUID DEFAULT uuid_generate_v4 ()
        CONSTRAINT users_pk PRIMARY KEY,
    deleted BOOLEAN NOT NULL DEFAULT FALSE
);

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS votes (
    id UUID DEFAULT uuid_generate_v4 ()
        CONSTRAINT votes_pk PRIMARY KEY,
    deleted BOOLEAN NOT NULL DEFAULT FALSE
);
```

In those tables, the constraint should disallow operations which turn `deleted` from `TRUE` to `FALSE`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think before update trigger will do the job.

```
-- trigger function to raise an error
create or replace function reject_soft_undelete_trg_func() returns trigger
    language plpgsql
as
$$
    begin
        raise 'Cannot change deleted flag value from true to false on table %',  TG_TABLE_NAME;
    end;
$$;
   -- create triggers on each table , 
create trigger reject_soft_undelete_trg before update on votes
    for each row
    when (new.deleted = false and old.deleted = true )
    execute function reject_soft_undelete_trg_func();
create trigger reject_soft_undelete_trg before update on users
    for each row
    when (new.deleted = false and old.deleted = true )
    execute function reject_soft_undelete_trg_func();
```

If you have many tables , you may generate `create trigger` statements dynamically ,e.g.

```
$$
    declare r record;
    command text default
        'create trigger reject_soft_undelete_trg before update on "%s"."%s"
    for each row
    when (new.deleted = false and old.deleted = true )
    execute function reject_soft_undelete_trg_func()';
    begin
        for r in select table_schema, table_name from information_schema.columns where column_name ='deleted'
        loop
            raise debug '%', FORMAT(command,r.table_schema,r.table_name);
            execute FORMAT(command,r.table_schema,r.table_name);
        end loop;
    end;
$$
```

Comment: There really isn't a way of doing this with `CONSTRAINT`s?

Comment: No, a trigger is the way to go.